# one executor running much longer than all the other in spark streaming task

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

[image]

I'm integrating spark streaming with kafka, in one of the stages, one executor runs much slower than the other..

you could find in the picture, h10.zw runs 2.6 min, and the "task time" is 52min, which is much longer than other executors. But the shuffle read size/ shuffle write size is the same as others.

I wonder what is the "task time"? What is the h10.zw executor doing? How to balance the running time of all executors to avoid time skew？

Comment: could you check the locallity of the data on that executor? Are there receivers registered on that executor?

Comment: Is it always the same node? Then you can just remove the node from the cluster, or at minimum, you could turn speculation on so that this slowdown is automatically caught and directed to a new node.

Answer (score 1):

This may, depending on your exact processing, be due to [data skew](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Transitive_data_skew). Try [speculative execution](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) and changing your partitioning to [smaller partitions](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/performance_optimization/how_many_partitions_does_an_rdd_have.html). This should help determining if this is the case.